# Apple's SwiftUI Tutorial: I'm Stumped

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift-structs

I've been working through Apple's SwiftUI Tutorial over the past few hours and have made good progress, but now I'm stumped.

I'm attempting to implement the "favorites" user input field within  LandmarkRow.swift and continue getting the error message "value of type 'Landmark' has no member 'isFavorite'".
"isFavorite" is listed as a variable within the Landmark structure in Landmark.swift and is also included in the referenced landmarkData.json file. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Here is the link to the specific section I'm referring to on Apple's tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input#Mark-the-Users-Favorite-Landmarks

[Screenshot: Landmark.swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQLZm.png)

[Screenshot: LandmarkRow.swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftc9I.png)

[Screenshot: Diagnostics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FooS4.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions.Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. Screenshots are not allowed as the only source of code. Please provide something we can use to reproduce.

Comment: Can you post your code? It will help people debug your problem.

Comment: I don't see why it isn't working (at a glance). Try rebuild the project with `command + B`

Answer (score 2):

Cleaning the build folder did the trick! As a rookie I wasn't aware of that feature.

For those who may come here from Google in the future, try:
Menu Bar > Product > Clean Build Folder

Thanks for the help.

Comment: As a daily user of Xcode, mashing on shift-command-K is a big part of my life.

Comment: As is deleting the DerivedData folder...